# Cannot insert new data into database with pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem trying to insert new data into database,
i don't even get any error

```
$db = new MyPDO();
$datauser = array( 
'account' => $acc, 
'tid' => $tid, 
'email' => $email, 
'amount' => $amount, 
'date' => 'NOW()',
'obj_id' => $object_id);  
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO account_reg_log 
(account, tid, email, amount, date, obj_id) VALUES 
(:account, :tid, :email, :amount, :date, :obj_id)");
$sql->execute($datauser);
```

Checking database after running the script and see no new rows..
Any ideas how can i fix hat?

Comment: Place `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so. Also add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Note that you can also send the error mode attribute to the PDO constructor so that you can catch most connection errors as well.

Answer (score 5):

You need to prepare your statement instead of running a query directly with placeholders.

Change:

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO account_reg_log 
(account, tid, email, amount, date, obj_id) VALUES 
(:account, :tid, :email, :amount, :date, :obj_id)");
```

To:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO account_reg_log 
(account, tid, email, amount, date, obj_id) VALUES 
(:account, :tid, :email, :amount, :date, :obj_id)");
```

You should also add error handling in your `MyPDO` class so that PDO will throw exceptions and tell you exactly what goes wrong when it goes wrong.

Comment: That didn't help, plus i have a function in query `public function query($query){
        $args = func_get_args();
        array_shift($args);

        $reponse = parent::prepare($query);
        $reponse->execute($args);
        return $reponse;

    }`

Comment: *The plot thickens* ^

Comment: @EvilNabster So why do you `execute` again after the `query` method then? And you probably need `$this->prepare($query)` (or something similar) instead of `parent::prepare($query)`. Correctly setup error handling will tell you more. If you need more help, you'd need to post your PDO wrapper class.

Comment: @Fred-ii- A PDO wrapper class that completely re-defines existing PDO methods. Yes, that could complicate things a bit :-)

Comment: Errr...um, yeah @jeroen Just a tad ;-)